# computing offset after applying CGAffineTransformRotate

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

After applying

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform, degreesToRadians(10))
```

it seems that it screws up the position of the view so that I have to apply CGAffineTransformTranslate(x,y) to fix it. What is the formula to compute x and y?

Comment: You have to set an anchor point and a center for the view's layer and the view respectively to mitigate CG and CA AffineTransforms position changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view's frame property is not valid if you have applied a transform to it. As the other poster said, only the center and position properties are meaningful if you chang the transform. What are yo trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to rotate N degrees and move to a particular position. If I just move (without rotation) I can do it with CGAffineTransformTranslate(x,y). If I rotate and move it does not fit properly and instead of using x and y offsets I should move with different offsets - x1 and y1. How can I calculate x1 and y1 from x, y, and N?

Comment: for what X and Y? if you know the starting X and Y position of a point, you can apply the same transform to that point and get the resulting value. You'd need to multiply your point by the transformation matrix.

Comment: Suppose uiview v is at position x1,y1. I want to move it to x2,y2 and rotate N degrees. The problem is that the following two ways are not equivalent:
(1) CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformTranslate(v.transform,x2-x1,y2-y1), degreesToRadians(N)); 
(2) Create V at position x2,y2 and then CGAffineTransformRotate(v.transform, degreesToRadians(N))
I want to modify (1) so that it behave as if I did (2)